# create an image out of a custom vhd using azure cli

Tags: java, azure, azure-cli

I see examples of creating a image out of vhd file and using that image file to create a vm. I am using arm mode and wish to list my uploaded vhd as an image. Basically i want to do step 5 in the following article https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-createupload-vhd/ using azure cli/ java sdk. I do not see any examples of doing this. 
There is a cli command 'azure vm image create ', but is it deprecated in azure-cli version 0.10.1? I have installed a pre-compiled version of azure-cli for mac.

Answer (score 0):

As I known, there is no evidence that does not support the command `azure vm image create` in azure-cli version 0.10.1. And you can upgrade the azure-cli version to 0.10.2 via command `npm update -g azure-cli` now.

For doing the step 5 of the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-createupload-vhd/), you can try to refer to the section [`Commands to manage your Azure virtual machine images`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-command-line-tools/#commands-to-manage-your-azure-virtual-machine-images) of the article "Azure CLI commands in Azure Service Management (asm) mode" to use the command `azure vm image create` with the `ASM` mode, please see the steps below.

```
# Sets the cli wording mode with asm
$ azure config mode asm
# See the help manual for the command `vm image create`
$ azure vm image creaet -h
help:    Upload and register a VM image
help:    
help:    Usage: vm image create [options] <name> [source-path]
help:    
help:    Options:
help:      -h, --help                   output usage information
help:      -v, --verbose                use verbose output
help:      -vv                          more verbose with debug output
help:      --json                       use json output
help:      -u, --blob-url <url>         the target image blob url
help:      -l, --location <name>        the location
help:      -a, --affinity-group <name>  the affinity group
help:      -o, --os <type>              the operating system [linux|windows]
help:      -p, --parallel <number>      the maximum number of parallel uploads [96]
help:      -m, --md5-skip               skip MD5 hash computation
help:      -f, --force-overwrite        Force overwrite of prior uploads
help:      -e, --label <about>          the image label
help:      -d, --description <about>    the image description
help:      -b, --base-vhd <blob>        the base vhd blob url
help:      -k, --source-key <key>       the source storage key if source-path
help:                               is a Microsoft Azure private blob url
help:      -s, --subscription <id>      the subscription id
help:    
help:    Current Mode: asm (Azure Service Management)
# Does the step 5 like Azure-AddVMImage
$ azure vm image create <ImageName> -b <vhd-blob-url> -o <ostype: linux|windows>
```

Meanwhile, I think the simple way for creating a vm from a custom image is using Azure CLI with ARM from a template, that you can refer to the [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-cli-deploy-templates/#create-a-custom-vm-image) with [the template sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-from-user-image) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I am working in ARM mode and i have uploaded my vhd blob in one of the resource groups. Now i just need to create an image out of this vhd file. There seems to be no option to do this from the preview portal too. So, is there no way to do this without using templates?

Comment: Since ARM is what is recommended to be used everywhere, i wanted to find a way of creating custom image using resource group. There seems to be hardly any documentation on creating a user image given a blob url, on non windows platform.